# Swedish robber translation

Tags: python-2.7, translate

Assigned to turn a given string into swedish robbers language, meaning every consonant in a phrase is doubled with an 'o' placed in-between. For instance 'this is fun' would be turned into 'tothohisos isos fofunon'.
It also needs to be in a function 'translate'. Let me know what I'm doing wrong. Please try to explain fairly simply, I'm not very advanced :)

```
old_string="this is fun"

vowels=("a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "o", "O", "u", "U")

def translate(old_string):

l=len(old_string)

for let in old_string[0:l]:
    for vow in vowels:
        if let!=vow:
            print str(let)+'o'+str(let)

print translate(old_string)
```

The output I get is 'tot
tot
tot
tot
tot
tot
tot
tot
tot
tot
None

Answer (score 0):

Your code had one loop to many.  Here is your code made a bit more pythonic.

```
# define vowels as a single string, python allows char lookup in string
vowels = 'aAeEiIoOuU'

# do not expand vowels or spaces
do_not_expand = vowels + ' '    

def translate(old_string):
    # start with an empty string to build up
    new_string = ''

    # loop through each letter of the original string
    for letter in old_string:

        # check if the letter is in the 'do not expand' list
        if letter in do_not_expand:

            # add this letter to the new string
            new_string += letter

        else:
            # translate this constant and add to the new string
            new_string += letter + 'o' + letter

    # return the newly constructed string
    return new_string

print translate("this is fun")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def translate(old_string):
  consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ")
  return ''.join(map(lambda x: x+"o"+x if x in consonants else x, old_string))
```

Working fiddle [here](https://repl.it/FE64).

**EDIT:** here is a corrected version of your solution:

```
old_string="this is fun"

vowels=("a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "o", "O", "u", "U")

def translate(old_string):

  l=len(old_string)
  translated = ""
  for let in old_string[0:l]:
      if let not in vowels and let != " ":
        translated += let + "o" + let
      else:
        translated += let
  return translated

print translate(old_string)
```

Working fiddle [here](https://repl.it/FFIR/0).

Comment: Hey thanks, but I don't know what map and lambda are. Can you maybe simplify it a little? Its ok if it takes a couple more lines. Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that this is a completely different solution, right? And that you introduced more advanced concepts? This isn't an answer to the question. This is "your" answer to the initial stated problem.

Comment: @Addison `map` maps a function onto a collection and `lambda` allows you to create anonymous functions (e.g. functions not bound to a name). You can read more about `lambda` functions [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'll update my answer with a solution corrected from OP's code.

Comment: @Addison I've updated my answer with a working adaptation of your original code as well.